# "universally administered" (ie unique) mac, uuid.getnode() in linux/python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, networking, operating-system

Question: Am I interpreting my `mac`, as reported by `uuid.getnode()`, correctly as indicating a "all attempts failed"?

I'm attempting to build a "highly reliable" but also all-human-meaningful globally unique unique identifier from any given linux box, using python.  This will be run for registering heterogeneous edge devices in a cloud system.  I believe my best best is leveraging the device's ethernet `mac`, specifically the `universally administered` variety, which is guaranteed by the OEM to be unique - so my question is specifically about this approach (but i welcome advice in the comments about better approaches, I just might need a separate question for them)

`uuid.getnode()` seems tailor made to this.  However, on an example dev box (vanilla x86 ubuntu desktop, bare metal), I'm seeing a failure to retrieve a mac - ***assuming** I have interpreted the documentation correctly.*  From python3 `uuid` docs:

> If all attempts to obtain the hardware address fail, we choose a random 48-bit number with the multicast bit (least significant bit of the first octet) set to 1 as recommended in RFC 4122.

I see a value of `0x6ffa3e5846f2` --> first octet == `6f`, who's `lsb` is set.

I do notice that `getnode()` returns the **same** value each time, which is not what i'd expect if it is a failure (I'd expect a random return value each time, per docs).

(Finally, circling back the X-Y problem in case I'm being foolish here - I use this mac (or a fallback from `secrets.hex_token`, if `uuid.getnode()` is indeed failing) to construct my `uid = "f{socket.hostname()}-{mac_based_uid}"`)

Comment: Can you check the machine's actual MAC address(es)?

Comment: that value did not match up to any of the macs on that machine.  I don't believe there is any mac-randomization support in the system, but there is lots i'm unfamiliar with at this level.  What I really wanted to know, first, was the specific question here - is this result of `getnode` correctly interpreted as `getnode failed`?